# Disk Image Mounter: Value too large for define data type

Tags: mount, iso

I have a genuine iso file of AutoCAD ~2.5gb, I can mount it in windows with traditional application like Poweriso & Alcohol but while in nautilus the error mentioned in title occurs.

Now how can I eliminate this error? And, or how do I extract iso to its contents at-least Winrar can treat iso as an archive....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what nautilus does here but you can mount the image on the command line without any problems.

1. Create a directory where you want to mount it, e.g. `sudo mkdir /media/AutoCAD` (if you want to use an existing directory it should be empty)
2. Type `sudo mount -o loop /path/to/file /path/to/mountPoint`, e.g. `sudo mount ~/downloads/AutoCAD.iso /media/AutoCAD`
3. Access the files via `/media/autoCAD` with any application
4. When you are done unmount it again with `sudo umount /media/AutoCAD` (it is `umount`, not `unmount`)
5. If you want delete the directory again with `sudo rmdir /media/AutoCAD`

Comment: Thnx, but i dont know whether the locks on every file (recall we used sudo) influence any program installtion via wine?

Comment: For just read only access there will be no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to *[Alcohol 120%](https://www.alcohol-soft.com/)* or *[DAEMON Tools Lite](https://www.daemon-tools.cc/products/dtLite)* is the `wine` command and `AcetoneISO` app, it's useful but not 100%:

- Here is an explanation [how to install wine](https://linuxhint.com/install-use-wine-linux/).
- To install `AcetoneISO` is to type the following commands in Terminal:

`$ sudo apt-get update`

`$ sudo apt-get install acetoneiso`

To set up to work any Windows app with one or more virtual disks, follow the steps:

1. Start AcetoneISO window, and then click the button [ **Mount** ] and select one `.iso` file to mount. Once it's done, the virtual disk must be in the following directory: `/home/<user>/virtual-drives/1`
2. In Terminal, type the following command to setup wine to get the virtual disk: `winecfg`
3. Once the `wine` window is opened; #1. Click the tab **Drives**; #2. Click the button [ **Add...** ] and select the letter 'D' and click [ **OK** ]; #3. In the path box, type the directory made by AcetoneISO `/home/<user>/virtual-drives/1`; #4. Click [ **Show Advanced** ] and select the type: `CD-ROM`; #5. Finally at the bottom of the window, click [ **Apply** ] and [ **OK** ].
4. To install an app from the virtual disk such as `/home/<user>/virtual-drives/1` is to type the following command in Terminal:

`$ cd /home/<user>/virtual-drives/1`

`$ wine setup.exe`

5. To run the app after the installation, is to type the following command in Terminal:

`$ cd /home/<user>/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/<APP_DIRECTORY>/`

`$ wine file.exe`

- To make a Desktop shortcut of a Windows app installed, [here is an explanation how to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut/1437386#1437386).

That's all, best regard.