# How to open or mount unopenable or unmountable ISO

Tags: kubuntu, 14.10, iso, ark

I downloaded two `.iso` files, but couldn't open them with Ark. So I installed 7zip using wine (software called wine, not actual alcohol) and was able to open and extract one of them, but I'm still unable to open or extract other one.

Also, assuming the iso files are damaged, is there way (or software) to open them?

Any suggestions?

Note: I use Kubuntu.

**Edit:**
Using:

```
sudo -i
mount -o loop /home/ftl/Downloads/folder/file.iso /mnt
```

results in:

```
   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: can you post the command you ran when you got that message please ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - I ran the commands you provided, and got those msgs.

Comment: You need to post the exact command you ran in addition to the error message. Without additional information, it appears your .iso is corrupt.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - I did add exact commands...

Comment: So is there anything useful in `dmesg|tail` ?

Comment: Looks as if the iso is corrupt, I advise you download them again and/or contact the person who made the .iso

Comment: You were right (partly). Files were incomplete. But still, Ark doesn't show the content of iso. I used 7zip.

Comment: Here is an explanation how to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/253570/disk-image-mounter-value-too-large-for-define-data-type/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds as if the iso are corrupt. Otherwise you can loop mount them.

```
sudo -i
mount -o loop your.iso /mnt
```

The files are then available under /mnt. Post any error messages you get.

If you want a graphical interface use gisomount

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountIso for additional information.

Comment: I added error msg.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it may be broken.
You may mount it using this commands on terminal:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/disk
sudo mount -o loop DISKNAME.iso /mnt/disk
```

This way it should be mounted to /mnt/disk
It always worked to me, if not, the image should be damaged

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it is a reasonable answer, upvoting ;)